# Error Code 1064 with ') ENGINE = InnoDB' at Line 2

Tags: innodb, mysql-error-1064

13:28:50    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Customers` ( ) ENGINE = InnoDB   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 2   0.00031 sec
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSgUK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must include some column definitions between the parens.

(Note:  1064 is very good at pointing exactly to the spot where the problem is.)